# Best practice on controlling worker threads in windows (native)?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, synchronization, worker

What is the best practice in controling multiple worker threads that execute the same thread proc using win32 API only?

I've tried many alternatives but I can't get it right. My current code looks something like this:

```
// thread proc
DWORD WINAPI thread_proc(LPVOID param) {
    while(1) {
        WaitForSingleObject(start_event, INFINITE);

        // Do some work HERE
        // Work finished, go back to waiting for new work
    }
}

// main proc
int main(void) {
    // create enough worker threads
    CreateThread(... thread_proc...);
    CreateThread(... thread_proc...);
    ...

    // Wait for work here

    // start work by raising event
    SetEvent(start_event);
    ResetEvent(start_event);
```

Basically I am using event to kick-start multiple working threads but of course this doesn't work as expected. If main thread gets interrupted between SetEvent() and ResetEvent() worker threads would just spin in while loop.
On the other hand using an auto reset event object would just release one waiting thread.

Also, I need the main thread to wait for all threads to finish. I tired a few different approaches but I was unable to make it work. I think I am just beginning to realize how hard multithread programming is.

EDIT: Grammar

Comment: Use WaitForMultipleObjects() with bWaitAll = TRUE to wait on the thread handles.  *Then* you can call ResetEvent.

Comment: Worker threads never terminate. They are just created in initialization and waken up every time there is some work to be done. Waiting on thread handle would never finish.

Comment: This seems to be typical "Consumer-Producer Pattern". Win32 API (Vista or later) provides Condicion Variable, and it's useful primitive to implement such pattern.
If you're unfamiliar with that synchronization primitive, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163405.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052.aspx etc.

Comment: One way to set up a producer/consumer with multiple Worker threads on Windows would be to use IO Completion Ports. They are basically multiple producer multiple consumer queues. You can queue your own custom events to them and have multiple worker threads listen for your messages. Workers consume events, to to wake all threads you can send N messages.

Comment: Another approach is to use the manual reset event combined with an atomic counter. Threads increment the counter using InterlockedIncrement, when the counter reaches the thread count then all threads have been woken and you can reset the event. This gets more involved if your threads can loop back to WFSO before the event is reset.

Comment: Have you added a volatile long to check if the main thread wants the thread stopped. And a volatile long as a counter of the worker threads that are running (which is incremented at the start of the thread and decremented at the end of the thread). Allowing the main thread to wait until all workers are stop. ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad idea:

1) Micro-managing threads is very difficult and error-prone, as you have found.  The way round it is to not do it.

2) Waiting in a GUI thread for work threads to finish, (or indeed, for anything), is just bad.  Signalling the GUI thread when work threads complete, eg. by PostMessage()ing, is fine.

OK, you have multiple work threads that execute the same thread proc.  They run the same code so, obviously, they operate on different data.  Could you provide some more details of what data the threads operate on?  I suspect that you will end up queueing task objects/structs to a pool of threads, but we need more details.

Multithread programming is not all that difficult - it's just different :)  Most important detail - it's nothing to do with code, (or, ideally, any thread instance), it's all about how you manage the data - how it's partitioned and how it's moved around.  Sadly, it's also about avoiding the really poor examples of how-not-to-do-threading that abound on the net :(

Comment: I am not waiting in a GUI thread. Data is a large buffer of bytes. Each thread takes a chunk of it and tries to find/extract something in/from it.

Comment: Downvoting because this is a non-answer. The asker asked for a solution to the problem of waking up worker threads. "don't micro-manage threads" is a non-answer. You have no idea why the asker needs to do it this way. Also, the question never mentioned GUI threads so you have assumed something that was not relevant to the question.

Comment: Downvoting as well. Same reason as Ross Bencina.

Answer (score 0):

Worker threads can be set to low(er) priority (the GUI (main) thread is of normal priority). It doesn't really slow things down (as long as you don't perform any operations in the main thread, that keep it busy), and your application will be more responsive to user input. Also, in thread_proc(), the worker threads could somehow yield, eg wait (Sleep) for a second or so, if "no work was found".

Another way could be to use APCs.